# parameter substitution inside function

Tags: bash, shell

I need to set a default value (y) when the user hits enter in `read`

```
validate() {
    local validated=false
    while [ "$validated" != "true" ]; do
            read -p "$1 " $2
            $2=${2:-y}
            if [[ "$2" == "y" || "$2" == "n" ]]; then
                    validated=true
            fi
    done
}
```

When I run this function with `validate "text" test` and skip the `read` with enter, the error `test=test: command not found` appears.
How can I use the substitution with function arguments?

Comment: Please explain why you want to use `$2` in `read -p "$1 " $2`? What is the purpose of the second parameter in the `validate` function?

Comment: $2 is a passed variable, which I want to use later with the new value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write a value to a variable with a dynamic name, you can use `printf -v "$name" "$value"`.
This should be closer to what you want,
though I suspect some further confusion and follow-up questions:

```
validate() {
    local message=$1
    local out=$2
    local validated=false answer

    while [ "$validated" != true ]; do
        read -p "$message " answer
        answer=${answer:-y}
        if [[ "$answer" == "y" || "$answer" == "n" ]]; then
            validated=true
        fi
    done

    printf -v "$out" "$answer"
}
```

Comment: `read` *does* work that way. The argument to `read` is the name of the variable to set; that name can be hard-coded or supplied by an arbitrary expression. `read -p "$1" "$2"` works just fine, although then you would need to use indirect parameter expansion to check the result, so the rest of the function is simplified by using a hard-coded name until you are ready to set the final value.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems, but you can see it easiest with your statement

```
$2=${2:-y}
```

Let's assume that the user passes as second argument the string FOO. This statement becomes

```
FOO=FOO
```

Certainly not what you expect. Now assume that no second argument is being passed. In this case, `$2` evaluates to the empty string and `$2=${2:-y}` evaluates to *y*. Hence, this statement becomes

```
=y
```

which is even syntactically incorrect. With this in mind, you can see that your

```
read -p "$1 " $2
```

doesn't make sense either.

When writing a function, the best way is to not use positional parameters in the algorithm itself (unless you have good reason to do so), but assign them to variables and use the variables consistently, as @janos demonstrated in his proposed solution. It is not only safer, but makes your program easier to understand as well.